# Почему данные не доходят?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Всем привет. Есть метод который отвечает за регистрацию: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выделенная строка вызывает метод: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот root который за это отвечает: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот контроллер: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути после регистрации пользователя редиректит на /api/role и в таблицу roles должны добавлять данные, но этого не происходит, добавляется лишь данные в таблицу users, в roles ничего не добавляется. в консоли просто undefined: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, редеректить так при аякс запросе нельзя, ты должен сделать редирект на JS при ответе с сервера.Во вторых, при создании нового экземпляра класса мы не ставим скобки, просто new Role;. В третьих, строка $auth = $request->all() лишняя. Все гораздо проще:

```
$role = new Role;
$role->email = $request->email;
$role->role_name = $request->role_name;
$role->save();
```

А можно еще проще:

```
Role::firstOrCreate(['email' => $request->email,'role_name' => $request->role_name]);
```

Comment: Вот тут я что-то не понял: `редеректить так при аякс запросе нельзя, ты должен сделать редирект на JS при ответе с сервера` А как правильно делать редирект?

Comment: @Евгений В методе контроллера ты должен прислать ответ, что все ок(HTTP 200). А уже в функции then() метода role во Vue сделать редирект. location.href='http://...';